# How can I fix "no module named blog"?

Tags: python, django

After creating a Django project, I right click the project name and choose open in terminal. I was able to run the server using `python manage.py runserver`.

Now after creating a blog app in the project using `python manage.py startapp blog`, I tried to run the server again but it did not work.

The following error message pops up:

```
File "C:\Users\Sam Iam \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib_init_.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog.urls'
```

How can that module be found?

Comment: Can you show us the directory structure of your django project?

Comment: It's expecting a `urls.py` in your `blog` app.  Did you create one?

Comment: Please refer https://www.skysilk.com/blog/2017/how-to-make-a-blog-with-django/

Comment: there is a urls.py in my blog. let me share the directory.  inside the django_project folder there is the blog folder. now inside the django_project folder _init_.py    settings.py   urls.py  wsgi.py  manage.py ,,, now inside the blog folder there is migrations folder _init_.py  admin.py  apps.py  models.py  tests.py urls.py  views.py  _init_.py